# autofill two fields at login form based on two fields on another website

Tags: javascript, web, firefox-addon, autofill

I work at an  office and I have to login one page many times as different users. I find their information in another website and based two fields and copy and paste these content in  other site. As  we have many customers and time is important, I want to see is there any way such as one browser extension to auto fill login form by one click.

Comment: I think you would have to make your own extension for this, doesnt sound hard at all.

Comment: how? please show me a reference about this that guide me. I have not any experience about writing extension.